# Splidejs video not showing

Tags: javascript, video, slider

I am using splidejs to load video into slides. The video extension is being loaded, however no video is being rendered. I have been over this and I can see any issue with the code.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@splidejs/splide@latest/dist/css/splide.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@splidejs/splide-extension-video@latest/dist/css/splide-extension-video.min.css">
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@splidejs/splide@2.4.14/dist/js/splide.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@splidejs/splide-extension-video@0.4.6/dist/js/splide-extension-video.min.js"></script>

<div id="primary-slider" class="splide">
    <div class="splide__track">
        <ul class="splide__list">
            <li class="splide__slide" data-splide-youtube="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cdz__ojQOuU"></li>
            <li class="splide__slide" data-splide-youtube="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cdz__ojQOuU"></li>
            <li class="splide__slide" data-splide-youtube="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cdz__ojQOuU"></li>
       </ul>
   </div>
</div>

<script>
document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var splide = new Splide( '#primary-slider', {
        video: {
            autoplay: true,
            mute    : true,
        },
    });
    splide.mount();
}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change only one line in order to get it work:

`splide.mount();`

to

`splide.mount({Video});`

or

`splide.mount(window.splide.Extensions);`

It depends in which way you included Splide CSS/JS files.

More: https://splidejs.com/extension-video/

Answer (score 0):

> The DOMContentLoaded event fires when the initial HTML document has been completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets, images, and subframes to finish loading.

vs

> The load event is fired when the whole page has loaded, including all dependent resources such as stylesheets and images. This is in contrast to DOMContentLoaded, which is fired as soon as the page DOM has been loaded, without waiting for resources to finish loading.

You should use the `load` event listener

```
document.addEventListener( 'load', function () {
    var splide = new Splide( '#primary-slider', {
        video: {
            autoplay: true,
            mute    : true,
        },
    });
    splide.mount();
});
```

Comment: changing to `load` event listener does not fire the javascript, the previously prescribed `DOMContentLoaded` however does. The video module just doesnt seem to be firing. I have checked versions are all aligned, so am stumped right now.